# Guest VMs in UTM has different IPs

Tags: ip, virtual-machine, utm

I am using Macbook M1 Pro and using UTM for running Linux VM. I have Guest VMs installed with Debian / Ubuntu / RHEL Linux. All the VM's Network mode is set as "Shared Network" in the UTM.

The IPs got assigned for each VMs as 192.168.xx.01, 192.168.xx.02, etc. But I noticed sometimes, the VM's IP address is getting changed to different IPs like 10.xx.xx.xx.

I googled and found that usually "Shared Network" is referred to as NAT and IP address will be in the range of 192.xx.xx.xx range. If we are using some other network mode as "Host" or "Bridge", then IPs will be in the range of 10.xx.xx.xx.

My queries:

1. Why the guest VMs IP address is getting changed? Sometimes with 192.xx.xx.xx and sometimes with 10.xx.xx.xx. I am not changing any of the network modes. As I used to SSH to these VMs, I want to have a static IP address. How to setup for the static IPs?

thanks

I am expecting to have static IP addresses for my guest VMs and also want to know the reason behind the IP address getting changed and also why with different network segments (192.168.xx.xx, 10.xx.xx.xx)